# Image not displaying in DynamicReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I have just downloaded the DynamicReports libraries from http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/index.html.  I'm currently using a Servlet under Tomcat 5.5.

I have taken two of their sample codes and everything works fine when report is generated as PDF.

Problem occurs when the report is generated as HTML.  All image spacers are not getting loaded, therefore getting X in browser.  Again, reports are being viewed using Servlet.

I checked the html source code and below are the image paths:

```
<img alt="" src="nullpx" style="width: 60px; height: 1px;"/>
```

The data is being displayed properly, only problem are images.

Anyone knows is DynamicReports is using an Image Servlet?  I could not find any configuration for this on their website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  You actually need an Image Servlet. It basically uses the same Image Servlet that comes I believe with Jasper Reports.

There is a complete sample Servlet. I just had to modify the images path and it generated an awesome report!!!. Below is link:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3065668&group_id=313754&atid=1320348